# Calling PL-SQL Procedure over database link from Java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dblink

here my objective is to call a procedure over a database link in java. procedure takes one input and has got cursor as an output.
to check if my code is working properly, I created dummy procedure in my database and tried executing. it is working, able to get cursor and play with it.
however when i am calling some procedure over database link, getting error as

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'HR_CLICK_GET_EMP_DETAILS@IBSLUAT1.WORLD' must be declared
```

I had a call with developer who had created these procedure. according to him procedures exist at this end and access is already given to my user.

Now my questions and queries are

1. is there something different, i have to do while calling a procedure over database link(code is below)
2. what are the things i should be asking to sql developer. by the way database link is right.

   ```
              String prc_name = "HR_CLICK_GET_CM_AND_ABOVE@IBSLUAT1.WORLD(?,?)";
                String runSP = "{ call  "+prc_name+" }";

               String runSP1 = "{ call  get_user_by_userId(?,?) }"; this one is working

                  try 
                {

                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(

                        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xxx.xx:port:SERVICE", "username", "password");  // uat

                CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(runSP);

                cs.setString(1, "705151");
                cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                cs.execute();

                // get refcursor and convert it to ResultSet
                ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

                System.out.println("Total Columns in ResultSet : "+columnCount);

                System.out.println("Now Analyzing column one by one:\n\n-----------------------------------------------");

                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++ ) {
                     String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                    System.out.println("Column No:"+i+">>>>>>>>"+name);
                    }

                }
                catch(SQLException s)
                {
                    s.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException s)
                {
                    s.printStackTrace();
                }
   ```

thanks in advance

Ashish

Comment: So you are connecting to the first database from Java and invoking a procedure on the second one? You could connect directly to the second database.
Or, you can hide the db link in the procedure on the first database, so that Java knows nothing about the db link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Oracle user's name who owns the procedure as a prefix:

```
username.HR_CLICK_GET_EMP_DETAILS@IBSLUAT1.WORLD
```

Comment: thanks but getting error as PLS-00201: identifier 'ICIS_SELECT.HR_CLICK_GET_CM_AND_ABOVE@IBSLUAT1.WORLD' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Can you select rows from a table of this schema? For example: select * from ICIS_SELECT.table_name@IBSLUAT1.WORLD

Comment: yes i am able to access one table over this link. did check this again to confirm database link is working.

Comment: Try to call it from SqlPlus: exec ICIS_SELECT.HR_CLICK_GET_CM_AND_ABOVE@IBSLUAT1.WORLD(...). Is it workong?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is "synonym".

SQL Developer has created a synonym for HR_CLICK_GET_EMP_DETAILS as HR_CLICK_GET_EMP_DETAILS@IBSLUAT1.WORLD

that is what he informed me, I could not quite wrap my head around that but able to hit the procedure.

but now ,  able to get get the metadata of a result set but unable to traverse rows.

I'm getting an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24338: statement handle not executed
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1018)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:291)
> at  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:213)
> at ashishtest.StoredProcedureCursor.main(StoredProcedureCursor.java:80)

I guess, new forum is required for this error.

also I am not marking this as solved as not sure how solution works.